Ubuntu 24.04 "Dead" Printer Choice Won't Stay Gone
After having printer issues since upgrading to 24.04 (a fresh install after the upgrade broke the system), nothing would print on my Epson WF-7520 with no errors either - just nothing happens. Often over a half hour after I tried to print, there will be one or more popups on the screen saying that it's printing but still nothing.
I just realized that under the Settings->Printers section, it shows two. One is labeled WF-7520 which is driverless and is the one that works while the other is EPSON_WF_7520 (also driveless) and it is the latter that does not work and will not stay gone. It returns instantly after it's removed so how can I remove it once and for all?

sudo lpadmin -x EPSON_WF_7520

@petep Sounded promising but only give an error that The printer or class does not exist.
